# Does json add any overhead compared to returning raw html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ajax call that is currently returning raw html that I inject into the page.

Now my issue is, that in some situations, I need to return back a count value along with the raw html, and if that count is > 10, I need to fire another jquery operation to make something visible.

The best approach here would be to return json then right?  So I can do:

```
jsonReturned.counter
jsonReturned.html
```

Do you agree?

Also, out of curiosity more than anything, is json any more expensive performance wise?  It is just a simple object with properties but just asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question reserves some discretion, but in my opinion, there is no efficiency concern with returning JSON instead of raw HTML. As you stated, you can easily return multiple messages without the need for extra parsing (I'll often have a status, a message, and data for example).

I haven't run any numbers, but I can tell you I've used JSON via AJAX in very heavy traffic (millions of requests) situations with no efficiency concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, json is the way to go. There is no doubt that it is a performance hit. The question is: is it a negligible hit? My opinion is that it is negligible. Javascript is pretty fast these days in the browser. You should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

JSON'll likely be more compact than HTML, since bracket/quote pairs are ALWAYS going to be terser than the smallest possible tag combos. `{}`/`[]`,`""` v.s. `<a></a>`. 2 chars v.s. 7 is a win in my book. however, if your data requires huge amounts of escaping with `\`, then JSON would be a net loss, and could double the size of any given string.

Comment: I think the OP means to have the HTML as a property of the returned JSON object in which case it should be strictly more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Sources of additional overhead include

1. Download size and load time of a JSON parser for older browsers
2. JSON parse time.
3. Larger download size for the HTML content since the JSON string has to contain the HTML string plus quotes at least.

The only way to know whether these are significant to your app is to measure them.  Neither of them are obviously large and none of them are more than O(n).